# recursion function repeats the number of times if statement is "FALSE"

Tags: shell, unix, recursion, sh, ksh

Hello this is a reprise of my earlier question, any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/ksh

test_1()

 {
  echo "Trouble"
 }

invalid_opts()
{
echo $1
if [ "$1" == "N" ] || [ "$1" == "n" ]; then
echo "returng $1"
return 1
elif [ "$1" == "" ]; then
echo "returning $1"
return 1
else
echo "returning $1"
return 0
fi
}

hello()
 {
echo "you are in hello, is this ok Y/N"
read hello_opts
invalid_opts $hello_opts
       sleep 2
    echo $?
 if [ "$?" -eq "1" ]; then
 return
 fi
echo "choose from the list below"
cat /home/devteam/dan/sayhello.txt
read hello_choice
invalid_opts $hello_choice
if [ "$?" -eq "1" ]; then
   echo "Before recursion"
    hello
 fi
 test_1
 }

while true
do
echo "enter from below
    1. hello
    2. hi
    3. exit "

read opt
echo

case $opt in
1) hello;;
2) hi;;
3) exit ;;
   esac
 done
```

So if you execute the above script and you are in the if loop before the recursion(echo "Before recursion") and skip the if loop after that you will end up executing the aftermath function ex. test_1 as many times as the recursion. How can i modify this script?

Sample execution:

```
 ./try.sh
  enter from below
    1. hello
    2. hi
    3. exit
    1
    you are in hello, is this ok Y/N 
    y
    y
    returning y
    0
    choose from the list below
    hi
    how

    returning

    you are in hello, is this ok Y/N
    y
    y
    returning y
    0
   choose from the list below
   hi
   how
   asdasd
   asdasd
   returning asdasd
   Trouble
   Trouble
```

Comment: What is the problem you have with the code?

Comment: @KLibby can you execute the above code? Make sure you enter the if statement and recursion, the next time you execute you will endup executing the test_1 function as many times you are in the recursion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive function shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487262/recursive-function-shell)

Comment: @shellter deleted the earlier post

Comment: @ady6831983 what is the problem with the scripts ? `So if you execute the above script and you are in the if loop before the recursion(echo "Before recursion") and skip the if loop after that you will end up executing the aftermath function ex. test_1 as many times as the recursion. How can i modify this script?` could not understand what you meant by it ?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is problem in your code structure, the function `test_1` is called in function  `hello` in each case. So when the recursive call of hello is unwinds it leads to calling of function `test_1` as many times as function `hello` call. If you change the part of `hello` function something as below you may solve the problem

```
 invalid_opts $hello_choice
 if [[ "$?" != "1" ]]; then
     test_1
 fi
echo "Before recursion"
hello
```

I will also recommend use of `[[...]]` and `((...))` conditionals instead of using `[..]`